Adding a Brake Light to an EBike Low Brake Circuit via Relay
My basic understanding of electronics is getting me into trouble again.
I want to utilize the 5V "short to ground" Low Brake system on my e-bike's controller to ground a relay coil to close a 52V circuit to run the brake light.
I have tried using the 5V circuit as the + on the coil, but it shorts once you connect the coil to ground causing the motor to deactivate.
I am thinking of (see attached pic) utilizing a different 5V source from the throttle + to the + on the coil, and using the 5V Low Brake as the -. This has me worried in that now I am feeding 5V to both sides of the coil. Could a resistor be placed on the + 5V feed from the throttle to ensure it's only working in one direction?
I also intend on using a flyback diode with zener snubber on the coil to prevent any EMF spikes back into the system.
Note the main circuit of the relay could either complete ground or complete +52V... hence the "or" in the notes.
Thanks in advance!

Quick update: I actually think I found a solution. Got a 5V relay module that can be triggered by a low (GND) or hi (5V) signal. It has an optocoupler as well as a flyback diode so it will keep the circuits separated as well as prevent EMF spikes. I've tested it on my benchtop with a 13V power supply in place of the 52V circuit for testing (and to not pop the 12V LED) via a step-down.
Now, when the Low Brake is connected to the sensor IN, it will kick on the relay when it senses 0V.
Testing tomorrow.


Test successful! Amazon link to the relay module used in case this can help anyone down the road.
AEDIKO 4pcs DC 5V Relay Module 1 Channel Relay Switch Relay Board with Optocoupler Isolation Support High or Low Level Trigger https://a.co/d/i1w8PEd

Welcome! What does the middle left side pin on your relay do?

The middle left is the "COMM" of the relay - the feed to the main relay circuit switched by the coil. I was planning on running the 52V the light needs to that pin, so as the coil activates it closes the "NO" contact and sends the voltage to the light. It could also be a switched ground rather than a switched +.

Strange. Is it bi-stable?

Its 5V actuated, actually turns on at 3.9V and only pulls .054A.

Is the "5V short to ground Low Brake" signal on your e-bike's controller an input to the controller or an output from the controller (or possibly both)? The behavior you describe when you connected the relay directly seems to imply that it's an input. It may also be an output, but it's a fair possibility that it isn't (in which case you're wasting your time).

The 5V is an output of the board. The brake lever interrupts the 5V to ground. That is what tells the controller to cut power to the motor.

Where have you found a relay that works for 52V DC?

It's a 5V relay... switching 52V. jqc-3f t73 is the PN.

"The brake lever interrupts the 5V to ground. That is what tells the controller to cut power to the motor." <- What you're describing here is an input to the controller, not an output. So what you're really interested in is the signal provided by the brake lever when it pulls the controller's input (with its 5V pull-up ) down to ground.

@brhans sorry for the confusion. Yes... the brake system is provided a constant 5V from the controller. When the levers ground that 5V the signal is sent to the controller to stop the motor power. If I can use that ground signal to also ground a separate 5V source to the relay coil it should close the relay for the tail light.

Just updated the original post... I actually think I found a solution. Got a 5V relay module that can be triggered by a low (GND) or hi (5V) signal. It has an optocoupler as well as a flyback diode so it will keep the circuits separated as well as prevent EMF spikes. I've tested it on my benchtop with a 13V power supply in place of the 52V circuit for testing (and to not pop the 12V LED) via a step-down.
Now, when the Low Brake is connected to the sensor IN, it will kick on the relay when it senses 0V.
Testing tomorrow.
